# git with an svn interface?

Tags: svn, git

Is there a way to interface a git repository using svn's command set?

**Context**: most of the members of our team want to switch to git from svn for all our new projects, but there are a few dissenters.

I know that it is possible to access an svn repo using git, but I'm looking for the opposite functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally no - not without making terrible assumptions and simplifications that are guaranteed to come back to bite you. Moving from a non-distributed to a distributed VCS, and making effective use of it, requires you to change your mindset. http://hginit.com/00.html has some notes on moving from svn to hg which would be similarly appropriate to this case.

Comment: This "advice" is not the answer, and yet you accepted it as the answer. If it was validation you were seeking, then the title of the question was deceptive.

Answer (score 3):

If not everyone is comfortable with the move, you can consider having a SVN server and ask whoever wants to use git to use git-svn. Git has a very steep learning curve. So even people who are excited about using Git, might have problems using it and in a project, it can kill your productivity. It is better to have everyone learn git via git-svn, since there is an alternative way to work - through SVN - if needed. If people are experienced with git, the move might be very fruitful. Otherwise, there might be lots of short to medium term problems. I have faced this, and am telling my experience.

Otherwise, TortoiseGit on Windows should be familiar to people using TortoiseSVN. Also, you can alias some of the commands in git from similar SVN commands, so that they seem to do similar things. Like `svn revert` is not same as `git revert`, but `git reset --hard` is kind of equivalent. It is hard to find equivalents most of the time, but you can for a few of them

Comment: That way, though, there's no incentive for people to use git instead, and the people using git are likely to get frustrated by the restrictions of git-svn...

Comment: @Mark Longair - totally agree with you, but updated my answer to give some more explanation.

Answer (score 3):

What I've been doing is using svn as the authoritative source, but all the git developers connect to [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/) while working together on projects. When tasks are complete, someone who is working on a paired task, for example, rebases as necessary and commits to subversion with `git svn`.

It's not a perfect solution, but it lets you work locally under git with the other git developers, at least.

What you really need to do is get the hold-outs onto git. That seems to be the only real sustainable long-term solution.

Comment: I still haven't solved the svn holdouts problem on my end, either, though. I'm living with git svn, and it's at least 10000000x better than just svn.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you may try [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) - it has similar interface with TortoiseSVN.
But this is GUI similarity, not console commands similarity.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I would be very careful with this. I remember reading something about a team where people had made lots of critical mistakes because it looked like something was equivalent to svn, but was actually different in a critical way. In particular there was a case where someone changed file A, committed to origin/master, and then someone else changed file B, fetched from origin/master, and tried to merge origin/master into master. In their "merge" commit they *unchecked* file A because they didn't intend to make any changes in it, effectively overwriting the first changes.